# Gitpages doesn't show changes when Git push is triggered

Tags: git, github

I have setup a blog at `pwntoken.github.io` using github's service: `gitpages` but after commiting my new adding a new post to the blog, committing the changes, and pushing these changes from the staging area, I somehow do not get the changes pushed at all when checking out `pwntoken.github.io`

To make sure, one understands my problem, here's a couple of steps that I did:

`git add .
git commit -a -m "commit to stage"
git push origin source`

What am I suppose to do here exactly?

It's worthy to note that before this, I did:

`rake generate
rake deploy`

But while I was on `rake deploy`, it seemed git was on never ending process and hanged down on `cd _deploy` as shown below:

[image]

I had to `CTRL+C` in order to escape. Is this normal behaviour while doing a `rake deploy` which never ends?

Update: I did a `rake deploy --trace` to look under the hood, but this is what it is:

[image]

Comment: did you check your email? github sends you messages when a deploy has failed. on which branch are you? gh-pages?

Comment: I am on source. I do a `git branch` and it shows me `source` which is why I am sure. Git hasn't mailed me yet. I will check again tho but what it has to do with Git at local? because it takes time and I have to `CTRL + C` to stop process?

Comment: According to [the docs](https://pages.github.com/#user-site) you need to be making changes on the `master` branch for this to work, unless I am misreading something.

Comment: if it is a personal website you must be on master, if  you ue github projects you must be on gh-pages

Comment: I am am unsure. Octopress documentation says I had to push to source, not master: http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/github/

Comment: No, it doesn't.  It says, "As a result, you'll want to work on the source for your blog in the source branch and commit the generated content to the master branch." and then "This will generate your blog, copy the generated files into _deploy/, add them to git, commit and push them up to the master branch."